# Unable to set httpclient head to keep alive

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I tried different methods non of them are working. I don't know where is the problem. 
so far I tried these lines.
1st

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
```

2nd

```
HttpContent postdata = postdata2;
postdata.add("Keep-Alive","true");
```

If I write `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Close");` it shows in fiddler header. However Keep-Alive is not working. I seen similar questions on here. But non of the questions got the answer.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i am asking for httpclient not httpwebrequest.

Comment: Whatever you are doing is the right way to do, so what do you meant by keep-alive not working ?

Comment: @RaviA. Because I want to send request with http alive so i don't have to reopen connection over and over again. in http head connection keep alive is missing. I tried to set heads keep alive but it won't work